# API_KEY youtube request

Tags: android, youtube-api

I send request

[https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&fields=items&channelId=UCA82IrHs0dFZ3WH1lc1wMZw&key=xxxxx"](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&fields=items&channelId=UCA82IrHs0dFZ3WH1lc1wMZw&key=xxxxx%22)

from my Android app, but I have response 403.

youtubeResponse﹕

```
{ 
            "error": {  
                "errors": [   
                    {    
                        "domain": "usageLimits",    
                        "reason": "ipRefererBlocked",    
                        "message": "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction 
                                    configured on your API key and the request does 
                                    not match these restrictions. Please use the 
                                    Google Developers Console to update your API key 
                                    configuration if request from this IP or referer 
                                    should be allowed.",    
                        "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com"   
                    }  
                 ],  
                 "code": 403,  
                 "message": "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed." 
             }
}
```

what is wrong in my request? the api_key is for my debug mode is right and it is active.

Comment: Are you trying to play youtube video in your app?